# one solar panel is getting more power than another panel connected in parallel

Tags: solar-cell

what if one solar panel is getting more power than another panel connected in parallel? say if you have two 500w solar panels and one is getting 100% solar radiation and the other due to a angle is getting 70%, would you get a total power output of 500w + 500 x 0.7w?
[image]

Comment: If you neglected MPT curves, you could hypothesize these two current sources to follow superposition. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289250/iv-relation-changing-load-resistor-of-a-solar-cell/289265#

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically **yes**.

You do not say the voltage and current ratings but just the wattage. Solar panels are rated with respect to voltage and current.

- Connecting two solar panel in parallel with same voltage rating will sum up the amperage. If two panels have ratings of 12V, 2A. Then, the rating of parallel combination will be 12V, 4A.  So, power will be doubled.
- Any panel which is under the shade can also act like a load. And hence a blocking Schottky diode is a must for both the panels.
- For a practical circuit, the power would be at max very close to 48W or lesser. Having a MPPT controller can yield efficient power transfer especially when there are multiple solar panels involved with a nonuniform shading or solar exposure. (One MPPT for one solar panel is also possible)